# PL/SQL Trigger: Facing bad bind variable error

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have tried everything but nothing can solve this.PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.BLOODBANKID' keep appearing. Please help me.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER count_stock
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON blood
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_countblood NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(bloodid) INTO v_countblood
  FROM blood
  WHERE bloodbankid = :NEW.bloodbankid
  AND bloodtype = :NEW.bloodtype;

  IF v_countblood < 0 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20201,'There is no blood');
  END IF; 
END;
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables and/or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites, make sure the statements are complete and compile, don't post just mere snippets), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito), the statement triggering the trigger and the desired result with that sample data as ASCII or markdown table (see ["How can I create a table in a post?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post)).

Comment: Oh and BTW, errors aside, your trigger would never do anything. A `count()` cannot be negative.

Comment: Plus, in general, a row-level trigger on the `blood` table cannot query the `blood` table.  If you manage to fix the syntax errors and the logic error you'll probably get a mutating table exception.

Comment: Personally I like the idea of implementing a defense against antimatter in a database. You insert a row and if it's an antimatter row it will annihilate along with some matter row in the table. If however, there was no matter row in the table, the table itself becomes antimatter, the count of matter becomes negative and you raise an exception. Is that what you are trying to do? ;-)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates that there is no column "BLOODBANKID" in the table "BLOOD".

Either it doesn't exist at all in the table or you used double quotes on the column in your `CREATE TABLE` statement, thus making the column case sensitive.

If for instance your `CREATE TABLE` statement looks like this:

```
create table blood("bloodbankid" number(18), ...);
```

Then there is a column "bloodbankid" in the table, but no column "BLOODBANKID".

When we access a row without quotes as in

```
select BLOODBANKID from blood where BloodBankId = 123;
```

then Oracle converts this internally into "BLOODBANKID". As the same applies to `CREATE TABLE`, the column names usually match. If you used quotes in the `CREATE TABLE` statement, however, then you must use the same upper/lower case with quotes in every statement:

```
select "bloodbankid" from blood where "bloodbankid" = 123;
```

So, if this is the case, I'd recommend you re-create the table with case insensitive columns.

(Apart from this your trigger doesn't make sense anyway, as has already been mentioned in the request comments.)